# Ho do i make div content height not overlap on content beneath

Tags: html, css

I am making schedule divs and when I add more words in some it overlaps on the content under, how to i make the div height expand with the content?

I have tried using using overflow:auto for the main div and it doesn't work

Here is my code pen link to help solve it

```
<div class="schedule">
                <div class="schedule-wrap">
                    <div class="time">
                        <span>9:00am</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="activity">
                        <div class="random-activity">
                            <div class="speaker-session">
                                <span class="activity-title">Breakfast & Checkin</span>
                                <span class="activity-time">9:00am - 9:30am</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

css code

```
.time {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #979797;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.schedule {
  margin: 0 15px 3.5rem 15px;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}

.activity {
  margin: 0 15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 65%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: rgba(1, 186, 186, 0.2);
}

.activity-title {
  display: block;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  width: 65%;
}

.activity-time {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.activity-two {
  margin: 0 15px;
  width: 90%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: #e7eaf0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Triciah101/pen/LYPymzw

They should have equal margins

Comment: You sould remove the `position: absolute` property from the `.activity` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you remove overflow: auto;and  position: absolute;
 from your code.

If you want to position absolute a child element (in our case the .activity elements), then set the father's (.schedule) position to relative. But then you will have to set position absolute with different values for each child separately.